# SQL Date Order Correction

Tags: sql

Working on a SQL statement here and I have sort of a stupid question. Ive got this date field that spits out various dates from years and months etc. I'm trying to order them correctly but i get only the month in order. Example is:

```
01-05-2012
12-30-2011
12-18-2011
11-25-2011
11-24-2011
Etc.
```

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.tran_end_time, 110) AS Date
FROM         dbo.ttdpur040101_CT AS A INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ttdpur040101_Audit AS B ON NOT (A.tran_begin_time > B.event_time_local OR
                      A.tran_end_time < B.event_time_local) AND (A.__$operation = 2 AND B.action_id = 'IN' OR
                      (A.__$operation = 3 OR
                      A.__$operation = 4) AND B.action_id = 'UP' OR
                      A.__$operation = 1 AND B.action_id = 'DL') AND B.class_type = 'U'
WHERE     (B.server_principal_name = @Name)
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.tran_end_time, 110)
ORDER BY Date
```

I would like to have it shown as follows:

```
11-24-2011
11-25-2011
12-18-2011
12-25-2011
01-08-2012
01-09-2012
etc.
```

Thanks

Comment: what were you thoughts on the 'group by' i don't see any summations.  Did you just simplify the query for us? Or are you looking for DISTINCT dates?

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering by a Date column that has been converted to a `VARCHAR()`. Instead order by the original date column:

```
ORDER BY A.tran_end_time ASC
```

Comment: I think it won't work: "if the statement contains a GROUP BY clause,... the sort columns must appear in the select list" - [ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That's because Date is a `varchar`.

Try it this way:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.tran_end_time, 110) AS Date
FROM         dbo.ttdpur040101_CT AS A INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ttdpur040101_Audit AS B ON NOT (A.tran_begin_time > B.event_time_local OR
                      A.tran_end_time < B.event_time_local) AND (A.__$operation = 2 AND B.action_id = 'IN' OR
                      (A.__$operation = 3 OR
                      A.__$operation = 4) AND B.action_id = 'UP' OR
                      A.__$operation = 1 AND B.action_id = 'DL') AND B.class_type = 'U'
WHERE     (B.server_principal_name = @Name)
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.tran_end_time, 110)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, Date, 103) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date], 110) FROM (
    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT DATEADD(dd, datediff(dd, 0, A.tran_end_time), 0) AS Date
    FROM dbo.ttdpur040101_CT AS A 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ttdpur040101_Audit AS B ON 
        NOT (A.tran_begin_time > B.event_time_local OR
        A.tran_end_time < B.event_time_local) AND 
        (A.__$operation = 2 AND B.action_id = 'IN' OR
            (A.__$operation = 3 OR A.__$operation = 4) AND 
            B.action_id = 'UP' OR 
            A.__$operation = 1 AND 
            B.action_id = 'DL'
        ) AND 
        B.class_type = 'U'
    WHERE     (B.server_principal_name = @Name)
    GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, datediff(dd, 0, A.tran_end_time), 0)
) t
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Quite important is "rounding" to date part only. Faster than converting to varchar is `DATEADD(dd, datediff(dd, 0, A.tran_end_time), 0)` - because it's just math that SQL Server can do much faster than varchar manipulation.